# Unable to get error percentage column in csv report generated from Aggregate Results in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm running a test plan and and wanted to get results for error % but when using Aggregate graph its showing error% column on GUI but the csv file where its results are storing doesn't shows all same columns

Here is the SS for the Aggregate Result in Jmeter
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBTek.png)

But in .csv format i'm not getting it. Though it have an error count column there ...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV3TC.png)

Can someone please let me know the formula for error% so I can use it in excel.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a CSV representation of the Aggregate Report listener you need to click "Save Table Data" button:

[image]

If you want to make process more or less automated you can use [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line) like:

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv /path/to/aggregate/report.csv --input-jtl /path/to/test/result.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

You will need to install these 2 guys via [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/):

1. [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/)
2. [Synthesis Report](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SynthesisReport/)

If you want to do this in Excel entirely:

1. Get the [number of successful samplers](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34):

   ```
   =COUNTIF(H:H,"TRUE")
   ```
2. Get the number of failed samplers:

   ```
   =COUNTIF(H:H,"FALSE")
   ```
3. Get the [total number of samplers](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sum-function-043e1c7d-7726-4e80-8f32-07b23e057f89):

   ```
   =SUM(D17:D18)
   ```
4. Divide number of failures by total number of samplers
5. Format the value as the percentage

   [image]